# HTML/CSS Different formatting on safari and chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to creating websites and I had an HTML/CSS questions I hope someone could help me with!

I noticed that in Safari and Google Chrome, my grey box is not where it is supposed to be (I assume because I made the .veryouter a fixed px, but when I tried to use percentages and resized the page and changed the page sizing, my text box started to move off the page! I'm trying to have everything stay in place when resizing the window, so I'm unsure if changing it to percentage is the answer or not..) I have attached pictures to show the difference, Chrome is it vertically centered while on Safari it isnt). //The code snippet looks odd, sorry about that!

Thank you for any help :) I appreciate it[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aCMQ.png)

```css
html{
 height: 97%;

}

body{
 background-image: url("Metakingpic.png");
 background-size: 1300px;
 min-width: 1080px;
 height: 100%;
 
}

.veryouter{
 height: 589px;
}

#outer{
   height: 100%;
   width: 550px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center; 
}

#inner{
 position: relative;
   background-color: #696969;
   opacity: .5;
 height: 540px;
 width: 370px;
}

h1{
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

p{
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.words{
 font-family: 'Londrina Outline', cursive;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 55px;
 line-height: 50px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 padding-left: 23px;
}

.font2{
 font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 23px;
 line-height: 32px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.image{
 height: 114px;
 width: 174px;

 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 font-size: 25px;
}

.arrow{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 z-index: -1;
}

.n{
 padding-top: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 width: 125px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Londrina Outline', cursive;
 position: relative;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Welcome!</title>
 <link href = "intro.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Outline" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <div class = "veryouter">
  <div id = "outer">
   <div id = "inner">
    <div class = "words">
     <h1>My <br></br>PHOTO<br></br>BOOK</h1>
    </div>
    <div class = "font2">
     <p> Press "NEXT" to continue! </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class = "image">
  <a href = "https://www.facebook.com/" >
   <div class = "n">NEXT</div>
  </a>
   <img class = "arrow" src = "Arrow.png" atl = "Arrow"/>
 </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the container center need to add the following style :

```
 #outer{
height: 100%;
width: 550px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 20px;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center; /* justify-content */
-webkit-box-align: center; /* align-items */
}
#inner{   
position: relative;
background-color: #696969;
opacity: .5;
height: 100%;
width: 370px;
}
```

Hope the changes will help.Try this code and let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion :) However, it seems after changing my code, there is still a difference between safari and chrome (similar to the picture I attached).
I tried putting the centering and margin part of the '.outercode' into '.veryouter' and it made safari the way I wanted it, but now chrome is not vertically centered. Maybe there's a problem there?

Comment: Can you please  set the "veryouter" height in percentage like this  .veryouter{ height: 96%;}

Comment: Wow! I had to add the webkit parts to body, veryouter, and outer and change the 96% for it to work, but it works! If you dont mind me asking, how did you know to change veryouter to 96%? 

Also, I'm not very familiar with webkit, so if I use (for example), "display: -webkit-box;" and "-webkit-box-pack: center;", would I also need to include "display: flex" and "justify-content"? Because whether I included or erased display/justify content, my website stayed the same as long as I had webkit (I was a little confused about this, I hope it made sense). Thank you SO much for your help!! :)

Comment: @webdesignnoob veryouter is parent container for "outer" and "inner" sections. also we set 100% height so it will occupy overall parent height. Actually tried to achieve the height with css calc concept, But it doesn't work in safari browser. We don't want "justify-content: center; display: flex; display:-webkit-flex;" you can remove, It dosn't affect.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for your help! I learned a lot :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 6):

This is most likely because those two browsers have different default css rules, I would recommend using a css reset, either use https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/

If you're not familiar with these reset css - they basically normalize the default browser styles. I personally prefer using normalize.css on all my projects.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion :) I believe I have to download something from the github website you sent? If I did so and it worked, would my website my normalized on all computers, even ones that did not download the css reset/file?